# fastcgi and ignored htaccess rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, fastcgi, php

Very strange problem here... I have done a lot of googling with no results.

I have apache 2.4. and php-fpm via fastcgi proxy.

I have these two files:

`/test/index.php`

```
echo "working";
```

`/.htaccess`

```
deny from all
```

When I call example.com/test, I got the expected error result. Script is not executed...

When I call example.com/test/index.php the script got executed and I see "working".

The same is for any rules(rewrite...) in .htaccess, they are ignored if I hit the exact php filename.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Many years later, I'm facing the same issue. Any chance you remember having solved this? The only thing I can add is that it does work, if you don't use the `.htaccess`, but rather a `Location` block within the global Apache config.